# Maven project can not be created in Eclipse through Proxy

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proxy

[image]Im using eclipse Neon and working behind a proxy.  Below message boxes are displayed when im trying to create a maven project using an archetype.

"Could not resolve archetype XXXXXXXX from any of the configured repositories."

"Creating xxxxx has encountered a problem. Could not resolve archetype xxxx from any of the configured repositories"

I have configured the below settings correctly.
1. Proxy settings in Eclipse
2. Proxy settings in maven setting.xml file
3. Add the remote catalog as "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml"

However, when i go to error description, it says "unexpected end of stream on connection" and it shows my proxy IP and port. Just to check, i have altered proxy IP in the setting.xml file and eclipse proxy setting but it shows the same IP and PORT in the error description without any change. I have no idea from where maven refers the proxy settings. Please advice.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you set username and password require in eclipse??

Comment: Yes  I could download plugins from eclipse market place through proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error made me struggle alot, I could download testNG and other things from eclipse marketplace, but when i'm creating a maven project i got this error. Because my internet connection is going through proxy. 
I tried all the above but i couldn't resolve this error, but this guy gave me the solution:

http://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/set-proxy-for-maven-in-eclipse.html

After the above procedure is done, then you have to delete the existing quickstart-archetype from below folder
C:\Users.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\archetypes

then restart the eclipse and create a new maven project with new project name.
Since this is only a proxy issue, so no need to specify the arche types and all. This should work if it's a proxy related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
1) Delete your repository at C:/Users/????/.m2/repository
2) Check your C:/Users/????/.m2/settings.xml for correct proxy config
3) Set you M2_HOME environment variable to <MAVEN INSTALL DIR
4) Add %M2_HOME%/bin: to your PATH variable assuming windows (remeber to start a new window after changing ebvironment variables)
5) Try a mvn clean install from the command line - GET THIS WORKING FIRST
6) Then try from netbeans, you do not need a proxy setting it should call the default mvn.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried the steps mentioned by you. But no luck. I'm using eclipse.

Comment: where does it fail?

Comment: after finishing the new project creation dialog box

Comment: You haven't tried the steps I suggested, you need to check maven is working from the command line first, try a  mvn archetype:generate to see if the proxy is working. Step 5 is the key.

Comment: Everything works fine when it is done using command prompt. I could create a project and convert it as an eclipse project. My problem is i can not create a maven project through eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Set proxy setting in eclipse neon as follows:
`Window->Preferences->General->Network Connection`

Now select `Active Provider` as `Manual`.

Now you will get three proxy entries to be configured HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS. Configure host name, port, username and password in HTTP and HTTPS proxy entries, but not in SOCKS. Try this, it may help.

Also make sure the username and password you are typing is correct.

After configuration please restart eclipse, it is required for taking the effect of configuration.

Proxy setting in .m2/settings.xml may not be required after above setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above setting is already added to the eclipse. but no luck

Comment: Yes Sachin. I could download plugins from eclipse market place through proxy. Im having the issue with maven only

Comment: I have tried almost everything mentioned in the internet. did not working for me. However, everything is working correctly with direct internet.

Comment: Could you try removing everything inside repository folder and then edit pom.xml like deleting one character and then again write it. Then save your file it will try to update. Try it

Comment: wait. Go to repository folder search for .lastmodified file and delete all of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136537/discussion-between-sachinsarawgi-and-kevin).